# Run Gulp Task on Build

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, gulp

What I'm trying to achieve is to compile and minify my scss to css before the build begins so that if I'm running the web app on the fly, it'll build, gulp will compile the scss and minify it, and once the web app opens it will have the new css rather than having to remember to run the gulp task before building/running my solution.

Currently I have this set up:

[image]

Using this code:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='compile:sass' />    
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var webroot = "./wwwroot/";
var paths = {
    scss: webroot + "scss/*.scss",
    scssDest: webroot + "css/"
};
gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});
gulp.task('compile:sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scssDest));
});
gulp.task("compile", ["compile:sass"]);
```

From my understanding, this should run the `compile:sass` task before the build begins, though this doesn't seem to happen.

What am I doing wrong? Am I understanding something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: gulp needs to know that the complie:sass task has finished.  The easiest way to accomplish that is with return gulp.src...........    Add the return statement.

Comment: It turns out that it worked as expected. What was happening was that visual studio wouldn't reload the .CSS file for whatever reason, so I was looking at an unchanged file but in reality, it was different. Closing and reopening the file showed the changes. But I blame that on visual studio. I'm gonna see if your suggestion somehow fixes that

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Sure am, I believe the problem is basically fixed. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was working as expected, though as Mark said, do give every gulp task a return statement, as per common practice.

The problem I was having was not a syntactical problem, but rather (probably) a problem with Visual Studio.

When my gulp task ran, it deleted the files in my css folder, and made new ones, this worked well, but I had the old .css file already open and visual studio would load no changes since that file no longer existed. It was open in a sort of code limbo. If I tried to double click the respective file in the solution explorer it would just point to the one I already had open (even if the one I had open no longer existed), which did not have the changes. However, closing this file and then reopening it loaded the changes. I believe this to be a visual studio problem and not a gulp problem.